# Can we inject javaScript on standard edit page of contact object?

Tags: javascript, standard-objects, inline

I have a requirement to make callout from standard edit page of the contact object. Is it possible to inject javascript on standard inline edit page or standard edit view page.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a visualforce and embed that visualforce to the record page with the page layout editor.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=accessing_layout_standard.htm

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005105&language=en_US

Comment: I was a visulaforce page  and add it in detail page layout . But I am not able to fetch the zipCode field Id in my script.

Comment: What you are trying to do it´s unusual, but you can try something like this document.querySelectorAll('input[id="con19zip"]'), replacing with the correct id, but I don´t know if it will always work. If you are familiar with firebug or other browser console I recommend you to inspect the edit page and see how the dom is rendered.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to access the DOM outside of domain, your inline visualforce page would rendered in a iframe.